# How to initialize class with empty dictionary - Python

Tags: python, initialization, instantiation

Apologies if the question is amateurish, I'm new to classes/objects. I've looked through other Stack posts, and haven't gotten a clear answer to my question.

I want to initialize a class with an empty dictionary, and then add the keys/values to the dictionary. How would I do that?

Here is what I have now:

```
class Network(object):
    
    self.dict = {}

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        """
        Initializes key and value of dictionary
        """
        self.key = key
        self.value = value   
        
    def add_key(key):
        """
        Should add the key to the dictionary if it doesn't exist
        """
        #if the key is not in the dictionary, add the key, and a value which is an empty list
        if key not in self.dict:
            self[key] = []
```

How would Python know that the `key` and `value` that I initialize are elements of the empty dictionary `dict` I created?

**EDIT**: I updated the code according to Ghost Ops suggestion, but receiving an attribute error when I try to test it.

```
class Network(object):
    

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        """
        Initializes key and value of dictionary
        """
        self.dicts = {}
        self.key = key
        self.value = value   
        
    def add_key(key):
        """
        Should add the key to the dictionary if it doesn't exist
        """
        #if the key is not in the dictionary, add the key, and a value which is an empty list
        if key not in self.dicts:
            self[key] = []
       
        # to test if the code returns correctly:
        def get_dicts(self):
            return self.dicts

test_dic = {13: [1, 2, 3], 14:[4, 5]}
print(test_dic.get_dicts())
```

The error:
`'dict' object has no attribute 'get_dicts'`

Am I perhaps testing the code wrong?/ Apologies, I am very new to this

Comment: you can put the `self.dict = {}` line into the `__init__` function so that for every initiation, it creates a new dictionary and also, name the dictionary with an another name like `self._dict` not `dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inherit your class from `dict`, basically your class will act as a dictionary too. Your `add key` method would still work perfectly fine, just change `self.dict` to `self.keys()` to get all existing keys back. Key, and Value variables are unnecessary.

```
class Network(dict):

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        """ Initializes superclass """
        super().__init__()  
        
    def add_key(key):
        """ Should add the key to the dictionary if it doesn't exist """
        if key not in self.keys():
            self[key] = []
```